# How to use SharePoint for storing documents with bibliographic information?

Tags: metadata

For researchers, it is important to have the bibliographic information (Author, Year, Title, Journal or source name, publisher, original URL, etc.) for a document, paper or information in general.

There are other tools which make managing, storing and retrieving such information easier.
Are there tools for SharePoint (maybe already integrated) which allow adding metadata like BibTeX or [XMP-Metadata](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/recoll_XMP/index.html) to documents in SharePoint easily?

Comment: what about using the a column for each param that you need?

Comment: good point - well, if it would be possible to create BibTeX entries out of the metadata easily, that would be an option. I wonder, if there are some best-practice examples already described for using SharePoint for such sources and syncing it with tools like http://www.zotero.org

Comment: Using metadata is the best practice. Also you can use the taxonomy to improve the searchability